# ProgressBar's progress display wrongly when rotated or resized

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I'm using `ProgressBar` to display the percentage of questions done in my application.

However I'm facing a strange issue, when the activity's `onCreate`'s method get called again (rotate, resize ..), the `ProgressBar`'s progress display become very weird.

I debug the code, but everything is fine, the setMax() and setProgress()'s value are also correct.

First Load :

[image]

Resize screen :

[image]

My `onCreate` method :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_practice_type_list);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        int practiceType = b.getInt("practiceType");
        int level = b.getInt("level");

        DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
        databaseAccess.open();
        ArrayList<BookInfoByTypeModel> bookInfo = databaseAccess.getBookInfoByType(level, practiceType);
        databaseAccess.close();

        ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.practice_type_layout_scrollview);
        LinearLayout topParent = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

        topParent.setLayoutParams(params);
        topParent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        View viewTypeItem;
        TextView tvTypeThumbnail;
        TextView tvTypeName;
        TextView tvTypeCount;
        ProgressBar pbTypeProgressPercent;
        TextView tvTypeProgressText;

        for (int i = 0; i < bookInfo.size(); i++) {
            BookInfoByTypeModel book = bookInfo.get(i);

            viewTypeItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.type_item, scrollView, false);
            tvTypeThumbnail = (TextView) viewTypeItem.findViewById(R.id.type_thumbnail);
            tvTypeName = (TextView) viewTypeItem.findViewById(R.id.type_name);
            tvTypeCount = (TextView) viewTypeItem.findViewById(R.id.type_count);
            pbTypeProgressPercent = (ProgressBar) viewTypeItem.findViewById(R.id.type_progress_percent);
            tvTypeProgressText = (TextView) viewTypeItem.findViewById(R.id.type_progress_text);

            switch (book.getType()){
                case 0:
                    tvTypeThumbnail.setText("字");
                    tvTypeName.setText("漢字・語彙");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tvTypeThumbnail.setText("漢");
                    tvTypeName.setText("漢字");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tvTypeThumbnail.setText("語");
                    tvTypeName.setText("語彙");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tvTypeThumbnail.setText("文");
                    tvTypeName.setText("文法");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    tvTypeThumbnail.setText("読");
                    tvTypeName.setText("読解");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    tvTypeThumbnail.setText("聴");
                    tvTypeName.setText("聴解");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    tvTypeThumbnail.setText("総");
                    tvTypeName.setText("総合");
                    break;
            }

            tvTypeCount.setText("問題集数：" + book.getBookCount());
            tvTypeProgressText.setText(book.getProgressCount() + "/" + book.getBookCount());
            pbTypeProgressPercent.setMax(book.getBookCount());
            pbTypeProgressPercent.setProgress(book.getProgressCount());
            topParent.addView(viewTypeItem);
        }

        scrollView.addView(topParent);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You forgot to [understand the activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

Comment: @Pawel Honestly, I did read that link but I still can't understand what am I doing wrong. Could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: you're inflating multiple views with same ID into the layout. Usually `Views` automatically restore their state, but in that case the state is overriden by "last" view with given ID in the layout so all the views (with that particular ID) end up "restoring" from it which causes save state corruption.

Comment: @Pawel So that means I just nees to check if the Oncreate is called upon a state-restored operation then I dont need to inflate   the view anymore right? Sorry can't check it now because I don't have my lap with me here until tomorrow.

Comment: if you don't inflate the views you will have blank activity. State restoration is happening in (super) `onRestoreInstanceState` method. You need to store your question percentage outside the views, in a way that is not affected by configuration changes and use those values when (re)creating the views.

Comment: @Pawel I dont need to store the percentage because the value comes directly from the database, and in this case it does not change. You can see the 2 images, the TextView value are exactly the sameMay be you misunderstood my issue?

Comment: Try adding `setSaveEnabled(false)` on all of your views and see how it affects the state then.

Comment: @Pawel hello, thanks for the comment, I added the SaveEnable option to false and the progressbar displayed correctly. I still don't get it why the `TextView` are not displaying wrong value but only the ProgressBar ? Anyway, please post your comment as an answer because it helps me solved by problem.

Comment: Not all views save their state. If I remember correctly `TextView` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inflating multiple views with same ID into the layout. Usually Views automatically restore their state, but in that case the state is overriden by "last" view with given ID in the layout so all the views (with that particular ID) end up "restoring" from it which causes save state corruption.

State restoration is happening in (super) `onRestoreInstanceState` method which is called after `onCreate`, that's why values you set there are lost.

To prevent that behavior disable state saving with `setSaveEnabled(false)` on views you're adding to the layout.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now =)